# Filter/hide online news that match criteria

Tags: webapp-rec

I read the news through some of the most important online newspapers. I am tired of reading always some of the most boring (for me) news that include always the same words; "football", "crisis", "Obama", etc.

Is there some kind of Firefox plugin or whatever that filters the newspaper's site and hides all news that contain these words on the title or text (at different depth levels) of the article?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for browser plugins recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know plug-in or extension that does it for you, but you can always use [Google News](http://news.google.com/) and instead of filtering out, you can choose what's you're interested in by choosing custom sections from the [Google News Directory](http://news.google.com/news/directory).

Comment: yes this is a good idea. I can also use some of my favorite newspapers as news sources and then filter (with minus) the things I do not like